# Android update error

Tags: android

When i am trying to update my application i am getting the following message in developer console.

**Error**: APK version 1 supports all the same devices as other APKs with higher versions. It would not be served. Please deactivate an APK.

Comment: May be You have some problem with the version number,Make sure your version number is higher than existing one while updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just what it says. You have to deactivate your existing .apk file before activating the update. If you switch to the simple view, it will do this automatically; in the advanced view, you have to do each step yourself.

Comment: thanks sir for replay. i more think is there a proper guide for the update process.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check you version number and check it is higher than the previous one.
Also for a detailed guide see
http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html and http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/publish-to-android-market/

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall existing .apk and install new one.